# Academic who abandoned literary criticism and started writing novels?

Tags: theory, identification-request, literary-criticism

A number of years ago, I read about an American academic who had been publishing about literary criticism and theory but then at some point (in the 1990s or the early 2000s) decided to move away from that and to start writing fiction (novels, as far as I can remember). He also explained his reasons for doing so in a journal article. Unfortunately, I can't remember the person's name, nor his reasons for moving his "career change". So who was this person and what were his arguments for moving away from literary criticism?

Comment: Reminds me of Laurent Binet, though he's French, and it isn't clear whether he's still an academic.

Comment: @CJSheu I didn't know about Binet's academic career. Has he published anything about literary theory?

Comment: I'm going off the author bio at the back of "The Seventh Function of Language," which lists his occupation as a lecturer. No idea about his research output though!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some more searching, I found that the academic and author I was looking for is [**Frank Lentricchia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Lentricchia).

In literary theory and criticism he wrote, among other ones, the following books:

- [*After the New Criticism*](http://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/A/bo27989983.html) (University of Chicago Press, 1980), in which he reviews and evaluates the "critical theory" (not just literary theory, since he also discusses the impact of a number of philosophers and Claude Lévi-Strauss) that came after the formalist [New Criticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Criticism) (see e.g. [Nelson Hilton's review](http://bq.blakearchive.org/14.4.lentricchia));
- [*Criticism and Social Change*](http://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/C/bo5953992.html) (University of Chicago Press, 1983/84);
- [*Ariel and the Police: Michel Foucault, William James, Wallace Stevens*](https://uwpress.wisc.edu/books/0596.htm) (University of Wisconsin Press, 1987);
- as co-editor, with Thomas McLaughlin: [*Critical Terms for Literary Study*](http://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/C/bo3627086.html) (second edition, University of Chicago Press, 1990);
- with Jody McAuliffe: [*Crimes of Art and Terror*](http://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/C/bo3622462.html) (University of Chicago Press, 2003).

[Apparently](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/frank-lentricchia/the-edge-of-night/) he was once called "the Dirty Harry of contemporary literary theory".

He published *The Edge of Night* in 1994. This was followed in 1996 by the article **"Last Will and Testament of an Ex-Literary Critic"** in [Lingua Franca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingua_Franca_(magazine)) (the same magazine in which the [Sokal affair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokal_affair) was revealed). This article is not publicly accessible in the [magazine's archives](http://linguafranca.mirror.theinfo.org/archives/) but it is mentioned in several other places on the Web, e.g. in a review of Lentrichhia's novel *Lucchesi and the Whale* by Mark W. Hornburg (my emphasis):

> Yet Lentricchia eventually left his department and, in 1996, in the pages of Lingua Franca, this giant of academic criticism **denounced his field**, **calling for a return to the pure pleasures of reading**. In the article, "Last Will and Testament of an Ex-literary Critic," the professor said he had been functioning within the academy as a divided soul, performing for his graduate students as "an historian and polemicist of literary theory, who could speak with passion, and without noticeable impediment, about literature as a political instrument." But the "secret me," wrote Lentricchia, was "me-the-reader"--who **felt so filled up by the experience of reading that talking about it felt inauthentic**. His personal encounters with literature were so pleasurable, he said, that they were like "erotic transport."

(The same review also mentions that, at Duke University's English Department, "Lentricchia was responsible for recruiting [Stanley Fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanley_Fish) as department head in 1985".)

A shortened version of "Last Will and Testament of an Ex-Literary Critic" was published in the [*ALSC Newsletter*, Volume 2, Number 4 (Fall 1996)](http://www.literarymatters.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/LiteraryMatters_2-4.pdf).

In addition to *Lucchesi and the Whale* (2001), Lentricchia published a number of other novels, including

- [*The Italian Actress*](http://www.sunypress.edu/p-4950-the-italian-actress.aspx) (2009) and
- [*The Accidental Pallbearer*](https://www.mhpbooks.com/books/the-accidental-pallbearer/) (2013).

Comment: Very interesting, but I'm also keen to know *how* you found this. I spent a while researching to answer your question, but it turned out to be very hard to find this guy by Googling for your description of his life.

Comment: Not every question can be Googled (or *DuckDuckGo*ed, in my case). I simply found back a 1997 of the Dutch-language literary magazine [Nieuw Wereldtijdschrift](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nieuw_Wereldtijdschrift), which contained a t[ranslation of Lentricchia's article](https://biblio.ugent.be/publication/267957).

Comment: A version of Lentricchia's "Last Will and Testament" is available in the [Fall 1996 ALCS newsletter](http://www.literarymatters.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/LiteraryMatters_2-4.pdf)

Comment: @verbose Thanks for the link! I have added this to my answer.